# animating a collision with an object following a path

Tags: animation, path, collision

I have this idea that looks pretty simple in my head, but turned out to be pretty hard to animate.
I've got this animated bee that is flying along a path, and i want it to collide into an object, bounce off and then continue the path. The problem with the path is that the object following it wants to go in a smooth line, not in a 'colide-and-bounce-off' line.
Is a path animation the right way to do it or is there an other, more convenient way?
Thanks allot in advance!

Comment: I think I would animate the path animation and then separately render the bounce animation and then splice them together in the VSE.

Comment: I fixed it now with some camera trickery by letting the first path stop at the collision object, then manually animating the bounce with the location parameters, letting the bee bounce out of view, and then letting a clone bee fly back into the camera view following a new path